# EventListener will not work on clones

Tags: javascript

http://jsfiddle.net/1wqdmo4o/

```
var whichSelected = document.querySelectorAll(".selected");

for(var i = 0; i < whichSelected.length; i++) {

    var clone = whichSelected[i].cloneNode(false);
    clone.addEventListener("click", function() {createOutline(clone)});
    document.body.appendChild(clone);

}
```

I have no idea why the event listener will not work on the clones. Any ideas is appreciated!

Comment: What is `selected` in `if(selected)`? You are not closing your `for-loop` and `if`

Comment: But i added a new eventlistener.

Comment: @DanielAbella So you are, my apologies i missed that.

Comment: @DanielAbella Can you please create a _short_ example which reproduces your issue, and also define "will not work".

Comment: Are you linking the right fiddle? It doesn't even have your above code.

Comment: You set zIndex = -1, so your clone is under the body. You can't click it.

Comment: Roman you are a god. I was about to go insane. Thank you!

Comment: @Bergi How is this duplicate of that?

Comment: @Arg0n: The code in the question suffers from the problem that all event listeners will call `createOutline` with the same `clone` variable (which holds only the last clone). That's what the OP means by "not working", isn't it?

Comment: @Bergi Nope, it was not working because he set `z-index: -1;`, so the node could not be clicked. Atleast the specific problem of the event not being triggered.

Comment: @Arg0n: Hm, there's nothing in the question about that… Maybe in the fiddle.

Comment: @Bergi "I have no idea why the event listener will not work on the clones".

Comment: @Arg0n: Yes, the event listeners don't work on their respective clones, they work on the last created one. That's the problem. Or at least *a* problem :-)

Comment: @Bergi That may be true, but the other problem, as stated, was that no event was triggered at all. Problem for all clones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the `z-index` of the copied node to `-1`, so when clicking, you click on `body`.

Also, the `id` is the same as the copied node, you might want to change this.

Comment: Thank you! Much appreciated, you are legendary!

Comment: @DanielAbella Please accept the answer if it worked..

Comment: Roman Granovsky came to the same conclusion about the same time, give him some cred to in his comment :)