# Clones have same listener even though they should be different

Tags: javascript

https://jsfiddle.net/d6rsq426/

For some reason, if i add one clone, both of them have different listeners and work separately. If i duplicate (using the t-button) the two clones that now exist so there's 4. The 4th clone works great, but the 3rd listener controls the 4th clone. I've tried to figure out for quite a while but can't find the reason. See the Fiddle. This function in the object is most likely where the problem is.

```
duplicateSelected()
```

Comment: This was what @Bergi was talking about in your previous question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33942679/eventlistener-will-not-work-on-clones/33943007?noredirect=1#comment55645254_33943007

Comment: @SébastienRenauld Not the IDs, the "Same clone in all eventlisteners"-thingy. Look at question comments.

Comment: @Arg0n: Ah, that. Removing my comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
var whichSelected = document.querySelectorAll(".selected");

for(var i = 0; i < whichSelected.length; i++) {
    var clone = whichSelected[i].cloneNode(false);
    (function(clone){
        clone.addEventListener("click", function() {createOutline(clone)});
    })(clone);
    document.body.appendChild(clone);
}
```

I have updated your [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/d6rsq426/1/) to make this work.

The reason behind this, is that when the eventlistener is called, clone is what it was last in the iteration (`for-loop`). By using an IIFE (Immidiately invoked function expression), `clone` is retained when the event fires.

Comment: Thank you, you are my personal hero today. So if i understood correctly, the eventListener thinks  that the clone that it's suppose to use is the last one that was created by the iterator? 

This basically means that without the IIFE i can put the eventListener either on top or bottom of the for-loop and it will still be fired only after the for loop has finished iterating and not the order it exists in line-wise?

Comment: The click-event happens long after the `for-loop` finishes, yes :). At that time, the variable `clone` might not be what it was when attaching the eventlistener. Please upvote also btw!

Comment: I would love to upvote but i can't because my reputation is still <15. There is still one weird issue with your solution though. If i press duplicate when i have 2 figures on screen, i suddenly get a total of 8 when it should be 4. Any ideas why that may be?

Comment: Nope not sure. I figured it out, i changed something else ofc, thank you for your quick response anyway! :)